# Inconsistent hash indentation in ruby-mode

Tags: ruby-mode, ruby

I've noticed that `indent-region` behaves this way in `ruby-mode`:

```
  {
    down_payment: 40.00,
    payment_day: 10
  }


  {
    "down_payment": 40.00,
   "payment_day": 10
  }
```

Both are valid Ruby hashes, so in principle they should behave the same way. My config for Ruby is:

```
(set-indent 2)
(setq ruby-deep-indent-paren nil)
```

Is there some configuration variable that I missed or misconfigured?